# Comparing Haskell's Data Constructor w/ Scala's Sub-class

Tags: scala, haskell

Let's say that my app has two types of errors:

```
λ: data AppError = FailedLogin | InvalidMessage deriving Show
```

It has `login` and `sendMessage` functions:

```
λ: let login user pw = Left FailedLogin :: Either AppError String
λ: let sendMessage msg token = Left InvalidMessage :: Either AppError Int
λ: login "foo" "bar" >>= (\token -> sendMessage "hello world" token)
Left FailedLogin
```

However, note that the return type is `Either AppError String`. I can't specify an `Either FailedLogin ...`:

```
λ: let f = Left FailedLogin :: Either FailedLogin String

<interactive>:18:36:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘FailedLogin’
    A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean DataKinds?
```

What's the reason for this behavior, i.e. not able to use a data constructor in `Either`'s `Left` type?

Secondly, let's say that I reproduce the above code in Scala:

```
scala> sealed trait AppError 
defined trait AppError

scala> case object FailedLogin extends AppError
defined object FailedLogin

scala> case object InvalidMessage extends AppError
defined object InvalidMessage                                                        

scala> def login(user: String, password: String): Either[FailedLogin.type, String] = ???
login: (user: String, password: String)Either[FailedLogin.type,String]
```

Note that I can specify `FailedLogin` as a return type. It would not make sense if I needed to call: `login >>= sendMessage`. However, if I only expected a single value on `Either`'s `Left`, would using a `case object` be idiomatic? Or is it worthwhile to create a `sealed trait ...` with a single sub-class, referencing the trait in the `Either`s Left`?

Comment: the error is on the right hand side of the `::`;  `Either FailedLogin ...` mixes two different things - `Either` (a type constructor) and `FailedLogin` a (data constructor) you need something of 'type constructor', in this case `AppError`. Note `AppError` and `FailedLogin` live in different namespaces!

Comment: I think the crucial difference here can be summarized as follows. Scala has subtyping (from OOP tradition), Haskell like most FP languages has no subtyping. This is why Scala is able to have `FailedLogin.type` as a type, which is a subtype of `AppError`. Instead, Haskell has no such type, only the _value_ `FailedLogin` of type `AppError`.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly stated: Both the `e` and `a` in `Either e a` need to be types. You are using a value where you need a type. The **type** of `FailedLogin` is `AppError`. One of `AppError`'s **constructors** is `FailedLogin`.

Constructors are ways to create a value of some type. Thus, for any data type `data X = A | B | C ... Z`, we can use any of its constructors to create a value of type `X`.

For example, `Maybe a` is a type and `Just` is one of its constructors:

```
> :t Just 1
Just 1 :: Num a => Maybe a
```

`Nothing` is also one of `Maybe`'s constructors.

```
> :t Nothing
Nothing :: Maybe a
```

The **type** is always the thing on the left-hand side of the data type and its **constructors** are on the right.

I can't speak to how `.type` works in Scala, but I'd argue that the correct usage of sum types in Scala would be to only speak in terms of `AppError` and not `FailedLogin`. If `FailedLogin` truly stands on its own, it ought to be it's own trait.

Comment: Using "constructor" there is a bit ambiguous, since an AppError is also a (type) constructor. "You are using a _value_ where you need a type" might be clearer.